# How to force WP to create a users table in multisite configuration?

Tags: multisite, multisite-user-management

I'm trying to update a plugin to support multisite and it seems like the plugin relays that WP have a single users table.
Since I want that each company will have a different set of users, I want to force WP to create a users table per site.

Is that doable?

Thanks,
Nadav

Comment: That's not possible. But you can assign users to specific sites, so they will never see the other sites.

Comment: How can I do it?